# CREATE DATABASE permission for asp.net application

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello I am trying to grant access for a stored procedure to be able to create a database. I am currently getting an error when running a backup restore script from the application: "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'"

I tried to grant access to the restore SP to create database

```
GRANT CREATE DATABASE ON dbo.my_stored_procedure TO [IIS APPPOOL\myAppName];
```

However this command gives me the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE DATABASE..'.
```

Here is the basics of the Sproc:

```
RESTORE DATABASE @new_db_name 
FROM DISK = @file_path
WITH RECOVERY,

MOVE 'CurrentDB' TO @new_db_file,
MOVE 'CurrentDB_log' TO @new_db_log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You don't grant database permissions `on` something. You grant to a user or role.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178569.aspx

You can grant `execute` `on` a sproc though. That may be enough to get the database permissions you need. If not, then either give the executing user the permissions, or look into impersonation.